# SharePoint Online cmdlets in vanilla PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell

Is it possible to use the SharePoint Online cmdlets (Get-SPOsite, etc) in normal PowerShell and not through the SharePoint Online Management Shell (SPOMS)? From what I can tell the SPOMS is just normal PowerShell with **-Command "Import-Module Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell"** run as a parameter when launched.

Is there a way I can manually import a library at the top of my powershell scripts so that they would run on a PowerShell client that hasn't the SPOMS already installed?

If so, what DLLs do I need to import for the Get-SPOSite cmdlets to become available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to use the SharePoint Online Management Shell, I don't, you can create a [profile](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613488%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), to help out.

```
new-item -path $profile -itemtype file -force
notepad $profile
```

Edit the profile to include the path to the SPO modules, as well as the [SharePoint Online Client Components](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42038).

```
#Bring in the Sharepoint modules
Import-Module "C:\Program Files\SharePoint Online Management Shell\Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell" -DisableNameChecking

#Add references to SharePoint client assemblies - required for CSOM
Import-Module "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Import-Module "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"
Import-Module "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.UserProfiles.dll"
Import-Module "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.Office.Client.Policy.dll"
Import-Module "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Publishing.dll"
Import-Module "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Taxonomy.dll"
```

Restart Powershell and you'll be good. If you work in both the ISE and regular powershell, you'll need to do this for both applications.